# How can I submit a Detail-tag based page?

Tags: visualforce, javascript, controller, controller-extension

I have a very simple VF page that displays the Detail-tag Opportunity page.  Within it, I have a Custom Button that calls the `finish()` JS method.  From there, I would like to submit the Opportunity within the Details-tag to the `finish()` method in my Controller.  Is there a way to do this?

VF Page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" extensions="OpportunityViewPageController">
<script>
    function finish(){
        //Submit to finish() method in extension class. How?
    }
</script>

<apex:detail subject="{!Opportunity}" relatedList="true" title="true" showChatter="true"
   inlineEdit="true" relatedListHover="true"/> 
</apex:page>
```

Apex Controller:

```
public class OpportunityViewPageController{

...

public PageReference finish(){
    this.op.StageName = 'Closed Won';
    upsert this.op;

    return null;
}
}
```

Comment: I don't have time to post a full response, but this post should help answer your question, you have two options JS remoting and actionFunctions: http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2011/05/tale-of-two-visualforce-pages-actionfunction-and-javascript-remoting.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but `ActionFunctions` cannot be used outside of `<form>` tags and Id don't think I can insert the `ActionFunction` into the main form within the Op. I think the Remoting has a similar restriction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need to do anything in your javascript function except call the controller method, you can remove the JS entirely and just add an `apex:commandbutton` to your page.  Commandbuttons need to be inside an `apex:form`.   Here's a minimal example, you can add additional tags to add more layout, such as `apex:pageblock` and `apex:pageblockbuttons` as desired:

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" extensions="OpportunityViewPageController">
  <apex:form>
    <apex:commandButton action="{!finish}" value="finish" />
    <apex:detail subject="{!Opportunity}" relatedList="true" title="true" showChatter="true" inlineEdit="true" relatedListHover="true"/> 
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

The `action` param uses merge field syntax to specify a method on the controller (which must return a `PageReference`); the `value` param specifies the text to appear on the button.

If you must have javascript, you can use `apex:actionfunction` to create a JS alias for your controller method.  Like a commandbutton, it must occur inside an `apex:form`.

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" extensions="OpportunityViewPageController">
  <apex:form>
    <apex:actionfunction action="{!finish}" name="finishJS" />
    <!-- you'll need to add the JS to call finishJS() -->
    <apex:detail subject="{!Opportunity}" relatedList="true" title="true" showChatter="true" inlineEdit="true" relatedListHover="true"/> 
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

The `action` param is the same as on the command button; the `name` param is the name of the javascript function to create.  You can use any name you like; I prefer to use the name of the controller method with "JS" appended.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think about putting a <form> around the <detail> tag.  An alternate problem I am seeing is that my inline editing is not working.  I'll open a new question for that, though.